2006 documentary about stranded Tasmanian soldiers and cannibalism
This is a 2006 documentary about a group of 6 or 7 (guess) Tasmanian soldiers during the 1800s where they get stranded in a jungle. 
One of the soldiers finds an axe and uses it to kill other soldiers and eats them as their food supply begins to run low. Eventually only two remaining soldiers are left. 
It is a true story apparently. But I cannot seem to find it on the web. Any help is appreciated.
The documentary was in English and was British. I think it was an hour long. The director was Meredith Fisher. 

This is Cannibalism: Extreme Survival (2006) produced by Meredith Fisher but wasn't concentrated on the Tasmania event although it did cover it.
IMDB is short on detail but fortunately, we have this unofficial review which gives more information.

Next we delve into a classic cannibal horror tale. Alexander Pearce was a prisoner at Sarah Island, a remote prison in Tasmania, Australia. In the early 1800's, conditions were poor, the labour hard and the food minimal. Pearce found he had nothing to lose and on 20th September 1822, he and seven fellow prisoners made a break for it.
They encountered some of the world's most treacherous wilderness terrain and were ill equipped and had no food. The group had the clothes on their backs, and just one axe - the instrument they were using on work duty before they escaped.
One by one, the group attacked and killed the weakest men and survived on their butchered remains. Seven weeks into their ordeal, only two men remained. With the food gone again, they played a deadly cat and mouse game, knowing that whoever slept first would end up as supper for the other. Pearce was the final survivor, though he was soon captured.


Thanks! I think that is the one although I can't seem to find any online version of the film.

No it probably won't be but we don't provide resources for finding content...only identifying what it is.
